# Can I Printf the name of a function assigned to a variable?

Tags: function, go, formatting

Is there a way to Printf the name of a function [that is assigned to a variable]?

From Go Playground:

```
func hello(name string) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Hello, %s", name)
}

func main() {
    testFunc := hello
    fmt.Println(testFunc("DoubleNNs"))
    fmt.Printf("%v", testFunc)
}

/*
Output:
./prog.go:14:2: Printf format %v arg testFunc is a func value, not called
Go vet exited.

Hello, DoubleNNs
0x499200
Program exited.
*/
```

I've found answers that instruct on how to print the name of the function being called, but not to get a string representation of [the name of] an arbitrary function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`reflect`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect) package to get the `uintptr` of the function and then pass that to [`runtime.FuncForPC`](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#FuncForPC) to get the information on the function.

```golang
runtime.FuncForPC(reflect.ValueOf(testFunc).Pointer()).Name()
```

https://play.golang.org/p/T3pmjd6ds1i